# Host multiple static websites in single S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We have clients uploading small static websites to single s3 bucket separated by folders. Each website has its own assets. We want to make this websites public using Cloudfront. So far I can host one website in root directory. Is there a way where I can serve all websites from different folders.
If I try to access index.html from subfolder, its assets are not loading because index.html is using relative urls.